# Mockito java.lang.ClassCastException: my.custom.class.Project cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have a Database Access Object that I am trying to mock. The code that uses the mock calls the `public void refresh(Project project)` method. I need to manipulate the argument and insert an 'id.'

The error:

```
SEVERE - EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: websphere.jaxrs.entities.Project cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
java.lang.ClassCastException: websphere.jaxrs.entities.Project cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
    at websphere.jaxrs.daos.interfaces.ProjectDAO$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$cf2a39e4.insert(<generated>)
    at websphere.jaxrs.service.ProjectREST.postProject(ProjectREST.java:105)
```

The test:

```
@Test
public void postProject_ValidRequest_NoContent() {
    projectRest = (ProjectREST) container.getContext().lookup("java:global/ProjectREST");
    projectDAOm = mock(ProjectDAO.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEFAULTS);
    userDAOm = mock(UserDAO.class);
    apiDAOm = mock(ApiDAO.class);
    apikeyGeneratorm = mock(ApikeyGenerator.class);
    projectRest.setDAO(projectDAOm, ProjectDAO.class); //override the real implementation
    projectRest.setDAO(userDAOm, UserDAO.class);
    projectRest.setDAO(apiDAOm, ApiDAO.class);
    projectRest.setDAO(apikeyGeneratorm, ApikeyGenerator.class);
    Integer keyLength = 40;
    when(projectDAOm.insert((Project) anyObject())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Project>() {
        @Override
        public Project answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Project project = (Project) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            project.setProjectid(10000);
            project.setCollaborators(new ArrayList<Collaborator>());
            project.setActiveapis(new ArrayList<Api>());
            return project;
        }
    });

    Map<String, Object> projectSettings = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    projectSettings.put("projectname", "Hello World");
    Response response = projectRest.postProject("user", projectSettings);

    assertEquals(204, response.getStatus());
    verify(projectDAOm, atLeastOnce()).insert(new Project());
    verify(apikeyGeneratorm, times(1)).generateKey(anyInt(), keyLength);
}
```

Inside the class being tested:

```
public Response postProject(String user, Map<String, Object> data) {
    Project project = new Project();
    project.setProjectname((String) data.get("projectname"));
    User owner = userDAO.findById(user);
    project.setOwner(owner);
    projectDAO.insert(project); // ERROR OCCURS HERE
    Collaborator c = new Collaborator(owner, project);
    project.getCollaborators().add(c);
    owner.getOwnedProjects().add(project);
    owner.getCollaboratingProjects().add(c);
    Apikey apikey = new Apikey(apikeyGenerator.generateKey(project.getProjectid(), API_KEY_LENGTH));
    project.setApikey(apikey);
    apikey.setProject(project);
    apikey.setTimestamp(new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
    projectDAO.insert(project);
    return Response.status(204).build();
}
```

Comment: did you mean `insert` instead of `refresh` as you method under test?

Comment: What is the signature of `insert`?

Comment: I apologize. I did mean insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `insert` has the same signature as `refresh`, it is a method that returns `null`. Therefore instead of `when(...).thenAnswer` you should be using `doAnswer(new Answer<Void>(){...}).when(mock).method()`